# Getting error using awk in applescript, but works in terminal

Tags: awk, applescript

```
    set Cppl to do shell script "Ctemp=" & Ctemp & " Cmobile=" & Cmobile & ";ls $Ctemp | grep $Cmobile | awk -F \_ '{print $1}' "
```

getting error awk -F _

I guess its '"'" problem.. it runs well in bash..

What should I put in?

Comment: If you [edit] your question to tell us the actual error message then we could better help you. Just saying `getting error awk -F _` is not useful.

Comment: Hint: `awk -F'_' '{print $1}'`

Comment: @EdMorton Since I am using Korean Version of Script Editor it shows error code in Korean. Found unknown token, xpecting """. something like this..

Answer (score 0):

Your script won't compile because the string contains a single backslash.  Backslash is the escape character for AppleScript strings, which means that if you want a literal backslash, you need to write "\\".  Change it like this:

```
set Cppl to do shell script "Ctemp= ... awk -F \\_ '{print $1}'"
```